# Contacts web part with columns on more than one line for each row

Tags: web-part, contacts

Is it possible to perform some kind of wrapping format on each row of a Contacts web part?

I am trying to fit 5 columns into a narrow space and want to avoid the web part scrolling off to the right for most people. Can I take columns 1-3 and put them above columns 4-5 for each row?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't offer this kind of functionality out of the box. However there are several Javascript implementations which can do what you're trying to achieve. Here is a [link](http://spjsblog.com/2013/08/12/dynamic-forms-for-sharepoint-v3/) for a pretty popular one which we're using most of the times. Other options like [this](http://spform.com/) exist too.

You'll have to modify the NewForm, EditForm and DisplayForm to fit your needs using those tools.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have budget for this and anything I do will have to be as a site admin - I have no access to the server.

Is the only coding option for this something pretty big in scope?

Comment: Alternatively, I could use something that would allow me to place contact details in a more arbitrary manner - not sure if there's another web part that will allow me to do so.

Essentially, I'm looking for any way to narrow the area used to display each of the site contacts (I don't mind if it makes the list longer, I just need to make it much narrower)

Comment: Even with CSS (which might be an option) or other custom webparts you would need to have access to the server. Although InfoPath is almost deprecated that would be an option too, but admin access required too. I'm sorry but I don't know what else i can suggest, if there is no budget and no access.